# r package KernSmooth copyright

Tags: r

I am new to R.   Was able to install a package called KernSmooth using R console.   Is there a place where I can figure out the copyright info for KernSmooth?  Below is what I did.

```
> install.packages("KernSmooth")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/KernSmooth_2.23-12.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 91267 bytes (89 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 89 Kb

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/yd/y63jsdgn2sx1jf9b7vl7ksqc0000gn/T//RtmpE1vO1I/downloaded_packages
```

Comment: `packageDescription('KernSmooth')` will show the description file where the license should be listed

Comment: The manual says the license is unlimited. "The string ‘Unlimited’, meaning that there are no restrictions on distribution or use other than those imposed by relevant laws (including copyright laws)."

Comment: Not sure what your purpose is here, but `citation('KernSmooth')` may be of some use as well. No copyrights, but quick citation information.

Comment: Thx ... These answers were helpful

Comment: This also seemed to pull back a copyright                           > require("KernSmooth")
Loading required package: KernSmooth
KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009

Comment: Are you trying to cheat on Coursera Data Science course's quiz?

Comment: I believe this is the OP's purpose too. I had trouble installing the package for the quiz and went in search of a fix and found this.

Comment: @Lucas-Soares, perhaps you are being a bit unfair to user3621202. Seems to me that user3621202 is merely asking for help in using R, rather than trying to cheat. The point of that particular quiz question is to get the quiz-taker to execute a particular command within R. The entire first course in that specialty is just an introduction to some tools and some concepts .. not really possible to do more than cheat one's self in that situation.

Comment: I personally took offense at the characterization of my integrity.  I remained silent all this time because I figured others would see the Lucas comment for what it was - misinformed. Thx to you @Oliver.

Comment: Ok, sorry if the comment was too aggressive. I saw some stuff on other forums that took me to the edge.

Comment: Apology accepted - am glad to put it behind us :)

Comment: Interestingly, the video lecture for the course segment associated with that quiz question explicitly instructs the student that it is OK to ignore the message that one must read in order to answer the question.  Specifically:
At 4:47 in the lecture titled "Installing R Packages", the narration states that some packages emit messages when loaded and some don't.  Then it states: "You don't need to worry about it."  This compounds the annoyance of the quiz question being about minutiae, designed without respect for the student's time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you just want to view the copyright, after you install the package, do a library() call

```
> library(KernSmooth)
KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009
```

[video explanation](https://youtu.be/xzvGA2zKLDc) (if needed)

Comment: how is this different from all the previous answers ... ?

Comment: the question asked just how to get the output which is through this. the question above this didn't have the code. this is how the response is different, it shows what goes into RStudio and what comes out, and limits it to just getting the information. Also, I'm assuming the person is asking from a course on coursera which I'm going through and I know they don't cover the getMessage, packageDescription, etc. So I am limiting it to what they might have been exposed to and already familiar with.

Comment: Thx Danesh.  Your answer was spot on.

Comment: The text responses from install.packages() are cryptic. I couldn't tell if I'd succeed or not. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: also, note that if you're using linux (e.g., ubuntu), you probably wouldn't be doing "`install.package`", but rather `apt-get install r-cran-kernsmooth` (after adding the apropriate repository); the only R command one necessarily needs is `library(KernSmooth)`. All the others are mostly superfluous (and (at the moment) not covered in the coursera intro data sci toolbox course)

Answer (score 2):

This question in Coursera was asked to drive home a point i.e. to use a package in R, it is not enough to only install the package. You need to load it too. This can be done by using library(*package*) command in R console or by checking the box against the package in R studio. The copyright information appears only after the package is loaded.

Comment: This is already covered, in greater details, in the previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you install and load the R package - KernSmooth you will get the following copyright message :

```
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009.
More information can be found out here : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/kernsmooth/+copyright
```

Answer (score -1):

you also can use this command:

```r
require(KernSmooth)
```

after run you see this message:

```
Loading required package: KernSmooth
KernSmooth 2.23 loaded
Copyright M. P. Wand 1997-2009
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as multiple earlier answers